# Spark SQL - load data with JDBC using SQL statement, not table name

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I think I am missing something but can't figure what.
I want to load data using SQLContext and JDBC using particular sql statement
like

```
select top 1000 text from table1 with (nolock)
where threadid in (
  select distinct id from table2 with (nolock)
  where flag=2 and date >= '1/1/2015' and  userid in (1, 2, 3)
)
```

Which method of SQLContext should I use? Examples I saw always specify table name and lower and upper margin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass a valid subquery as a `dbtable` argument. For example in Scala:

```scala
val query = """(SELECT TOP 1000 
  -- and the rest of your query
  -- ...
) AS tmp  -- alias is mandatory*"""   

val url: String = ??? 

val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
  .options(Map("url" -> url, "dbtable" -> query))
  .load()
```

---

* Hive Language Manual SubQueries: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I just used a read.jdbc instead of read.format

sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table, prop)

Answer (score -3):

```
val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/scala_db?user=scala_user"
Class.forName(driver)

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)

val df2 = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable", "(select id,last_name from emps) e")
      .option("user", "scala_user")
      .load()
```

The key is "(select id,last_name from emps) e", here you can write a subquery in place of table_name.

Comment: Can you add more details and an explanation? Please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sure. There will be a blog on this.