# In Apache Spark 2.0.0, is it possible to fetch a query from an external database (rather than grab the whole table)?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark

Using pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("spark play")\
    .getOrCreate()    

df = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:port")\
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")\
    .option("user", "username")\
    .option("password", "password")\
    .load()
```

Rather than fetch "schema.tablename", I would prefer to grab the result set of a query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Same as in 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34365692) you can pass valid subquery as `dbtable` argument for example:

```
...
.option("dbtable", "(SELECT foo, bar FROM schema.tablename) AS tmp")
...
```

Comment: At least in `Scala` (not sure of `Python` / `R`), you can give `spark.read.jdbc(url, s"($sql) ql", properties)` where `sql` is a `String` containing your actual `SQL` *query* [`Spark 2.2.0`]

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I try to use a custom sql, but table names work just fine :(

This is using pyspark2, with teradata jdbc