# How to execute select query on oracle database using pi spark?

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have written a program using pyspark to connect to oracle database and fetch data. Below command works fine and returns the contents of the table:

```
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@dbserver:port/dbname")
    .option("dbtable","SCHEMA.TABLE")
    .option("driver","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    .load().show()
```

Now I do not want to load the entire table data. I want to load selected records. Can I specify select query as part of this command? If yes how?

Note: I can use dataframe and execute select query on the top of it but I do not want to do it. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery in `dbtable` option

```
.option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM tableName) AS tmp where x = 1")
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729436/in-apache-spark-2-0-0-is-it-possible-to-fetch-a-query-from-an-external-database) is similar question, but about MySQL

Answer (score 0):

In general, the optimizer SHOULD be able to push down any relevant select and where elements so if you now do df.select("a","b","c").where("d<10") then in general this should be pushed down to oracle. You can check it by doing df.explain(true) on the final dataframe.