# How to compare two structypes in Scala and change datatype of columns in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to move data from GP to HDFS using Scala & Spark.

```
val execQuery    = "select * from schema.tablename"
val yearDF       = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl).option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2016").option("user", devUserName).option("password", devPassword).option("partitionColumn","header_id").option("lowerBound", 19919927).option("upperBound", 28684058).option("numPartitions",30).load()
val yearDFSchema = yearDF.schema
```

The schema for yearDF is:

```
root
 |-- source_system_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_refresh_delay_min: decimal(38,30) (nullable = true)
 |-- release_number: decimal(38,30) (nullable = true)
 |-- change_number: decimal(38,30) (nullable = true)
 |-- interface_queue_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rework_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fdm_application_id: decimal(15,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- history_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
```

The schema of same table on hive which is given by our project:

```
val hiveColumns = source_system_name:String|description:String|creation_date:Timestamp|status:String|status_date:Timestamp|table_refresh_delay_min:Timestamp|release_number:Double|change_number:Double|interface_queue_enabled_flag:String|rework_enabled_flag:String|fdm_application_id:Bigint|history_enabled_flag:String
```

So I took hiveColumns and created a new StructType as given below:

```
def convertDatatype(datatype: String): DataType = {
  val convert = datatype match {
    case "string"     => StringType
    case "bigint"     => LongType
    case "int"        => IntegerType
    case "double"     => DoubleType
    case "date"       => TimestampType
    case "boolean"    => BooleanType
    case "timestamp"  => TimestampType
  }
  convert
}


val schemaList = hiveColumns.split("\\|")
val newSchema  = new StructType(schemaList.map(col => col.split(":")).map(e => StructField(e(0), convertDatatype(e(1)), true)))
newSchema.printTreeString()
```

```
root
 |-- source_system_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_refresh_delay_min: double (nullable = true)
 |-- release_number: double (nullable = true)
 |-- change_number: double (nullable = true)
 |-- interface_queue_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rework_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fdm_application_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- history_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
```

When I try to apply my new schema: schemaStructType on yearDF as below, I get the exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.math.BigDecimal is not a valid external type for schema of double
```

The exception occurs due to conversion of decimal to double. 
What I don't understand is how can I convert the datatype of columns: `table_refresh_delay_min, release_number, change_number, fdm_application_id` in the StructType: `newSchema` from `DoubleType` to their corresponding datatypes present in yearDF's Schema. i.e.

If the column in `yearDFSchema` has a decimal datatype with precision more than zero, in this case decimal(38,30), I need to convert the same column's datatype in `newSchema` to `DecimalType(38,30)`

Could anyone let me know how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this occur when you try to apply schema on `RDD[Row]`, using *Developer's API* functions:

```
def createDataFrame(rows: List[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: JavaRDD[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
```

In such cases stored data types have to match external (i.e. *Value type in Scala*) data types [as listed in the official SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) and no type casting or coercion is applied.

Therefore it is your responsibility as an user to ensure that the date and schema are compatible.

The description of the problem you've provided indicates rather different scenario, which asks for `CAST`. Let's create dataset with exact the same schema as in your example:

```
val yearDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  sc.parallelize(Seq[Row]()),
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("source_system_name", StringType),
    StructField("table_refresh_delay_min", DecimalType(38, 30)),
    StructField("release_number", DecimalType(38, 30)),
    StructField("change_number", DecimalType(38, 30)),
    StructField("interface_queue_enabled_flag", StringType),
    StructField("rework_enabled_flag", StringType),
    StructField("fdm_application_id", DecimalType(15, 0)),
    StructField("history_enabled_flag", StringType)
)))

yearDF.printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- source_system_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_refresh_delay_min: decimal(38,30) (nullable = true)
 |-- release_number: decimal(38,30) (nullable = true)
 |-- change_number: decimal(38,30) (nullable = true)
 |-- interface_queue_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rework_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fdm_application_id: decimal(15,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- history_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
```

and desired types like

```
val dtypes = Seq(
  "source_system_name" -> "string",
  "table_refresh_delay_min" -> "double",
  "release_number" -> "double",
  "change_number" -> "double",
  "interface_queue_enabled_flag" -> "string",
  "rework_enabled_flag" -> "string",
  "fdm_application_id" -> "long",
  "history_enabled_flag" -> "string"
)
```

then you can just map:

```
val mapping = dtypes.toMap

yearDF.select(yearDF.columns.map { c => col(c).cast(mapping(c)) }: _*).printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- source_system_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_refresh_delay_min: double (nullable = true)
 |-- release_number: double (nullable = true)
 |-- change_number: double (nullable = true)
 |-- interface_queue_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rework_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fdm_application_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- history_enabled_flag: string (nullable = true)
```

This of course assumes that actual and desired types are compatible, and [`CAST` is allowed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0df29bfbdc6ec7f3ba7d7b54e024059b3894da16/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Cast.scala#L37-L91).

If you still experience problems due you to peculiarities of specific JDBC driver, you should consider placing cast directly in the query, either manually ([In Apache Spark 2.0.0, is it possible to fetch a query from an external database (rather than grab the whole table)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38729436/10938362))

```
val externalDtypes = Seq(
  "source_system_name" -> "text",
  "table_refresh_delay_min" -> "double precision",
  "release_number" -> "float8",
  "change_number" -> "float8",
  "interface_queue_enabled_flag" -> "string",
  "rework_enabled_flag" -> "string",
  "fdm_application_id" -> "bigint",
  "history_enabled_flag" -> "string"
)

val externalDtypes = dtypes.map { 
  case (c, t) => s"CAST(`$c` AS $t)" 
} .mkString(", ")

val dbTable = s"""(select $fields from schema.tablename) as tmp"""
```

or through custom schema:

```
spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option(
    "customSchema",
    dtypes.map { case (c, t) => s"`$c` $t" } .mkString(", "))
  ...
  .load()
```