# How to fix the exception: java.math.BigDecimal is not a valid external type for schema of double while re-applying schema on a datadframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to move data from table: system_releases from Greenplum to Hive in the below manner:

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "urltemplate;MaxNumericScale=30;MaxNumericPrecision=40;")
                                      .option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2016")
                                      .option("user", "user")
                                      .option("password", "pwd")
                                      .option("partitionColumn","release_number")
                                      .option("lowerBound", 306)
                                      .option("upperBound", 500)
                                      .option("numPartitions",2)
                                      .load()
```

Inferred Schema of the dataFrame yearDF by spark:

```
description:string
status_date:timestamp
time_zone:string
table_refresh_delay_min:decimal(38,30)
online_patching_enabled_flag:string
release_number:decimal(38,30)
change_number:decimal(38,30)
interface_queue_enabled_flag:string
rework_enabled_flag:string
smart_transfer_enabled_flag:string
patch_number:decimal(38,30)
threading_enabled_flag:string
drm_gl_source_name:string
reverted_flag:string
table_refresh_delay_min_text:string
release_number_text:string
change_number_text:string
```

I have the same table on hive with following datatypes:

```
val hiveCols=string,status_date:timestamp,time_zone:string,table_refresh_delay_min:double,online_patching_enabled_flag:string,release_number:double,change_number:double,interface_queue_enabled_flag:string,rework_enabled_flag:string,smart_transfer_enabled_flag:string,patch_number:double,threading_enabled_flag:string,drm_gl_source_name:string,reverted_flag:string,table_refresh_delay_min_text:string,release_number_text:string,change_number_text:string
```

The columns: `table_refresh_delay_min, release_number, change_number and patch_number` are giving too many decimal points even though there aren't many in GP.
So I tried to save it as a CSV file to take a look at how data is being read by spark.
For example, the max number of release_number on GP is: 306.00 but in the csv file I saved the dataframe: yearDF, the value becoms 306.000000000000000000.

I tried to take the hive table schema and converted to StructType to apply that on yearDF as below.

```
def convertDatatype(datatype: String): DataType = {
  val convert = datatype match {
    case "string"     => StringType
    case "bigint"     => LongType
    case "int"        => IntegerType
    case "double"     => DoubleType
    case "date"       => TimestampType
    case "boolean"    => BooleanType
    case "timestamp"  => TimestampType
  }
  convert
}

val schemaList        = hiveCols.split(",")
val schemaStructType  = new StructType(schemaList.map(col => col.split(":")).map(e => StructField(e(0), convertDatatype(e(1)), true)))
val newDF = spark.createDataFrame(yearDF.rdd, schemaStructType)
newDF.write.format("csv").save("hdfs/location")
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.math.BigDecimal is not a valid external type for schema of double
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.evalIfFalseExpr8$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_2$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:287)
    ... 17 more
```

I tried to cast the decimal columns into DoubleType in the below manner but I still face the same exception.

```
  val pattern = """DecimalType\(\d+,(\d+)\)""".r
  val df2 = dataDF.dtypes.
    collect{ case (dn, dt) if pattern.findFirstMatchIn(dt).map(_.group(1)).getOrElse("0") != "0" => dn }.
    foldLeft(dataDF)((accDF, c) => accDF.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("Double")))

   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.math.BigDecimal is not a valid external type for schema of double
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.evalIfFalseExpr8$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_2$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:287)
    ... 17 more
```

I am out of ideas after trying to implement the above two ways.
Could anyone let me know how can I cast the columns of a dataframe properly to the required datatypes ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two structypes in Scala and change datatype of columns in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501841/how-to-compare-two-structypes-in-scala-and-change-datatype-of-columns-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when you converting RDD to DF, you would need to specify exactly the same type as what spark schema used.

For example, when you do a `printSchema` on your `yearDF` DataFrame and you got this

```
description:string
status_date:timestamp
time_zone:string
table_refresh_delay_min:decimal(38,30)
online_patching_enabled_flag:string
release_number:decimal(38,30)
change_number:decimal(38,30)
interface_queue_enabled_flag:string
rework_enabled_flag:string
smart_transfer_enabled_flag:string
patch_number:decimal(38,30)
threading_enabled_flag:string
drm_gl_source_name:string
reverted_flag:string
table_refresh_delay_min_text:string
release_number_text:string
change_number_text:string
```

When you converting RDD to DF, for those fields have `decimal(38,30)`,  **Have to** be specified as `DecimalType(38,30)`  insteads of `DoubleType` you used.

Hope it helps!