# Loading data from JDBC source in spark java

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark

I am trying to load data from a relational database in spark with Java language via the following code:

```
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read()
 .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load();
```

as it is mentioned in the official documentation of spark `https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html`
, instead of schema.tablename, anything that is valid in a FROM clause of a SQL query can be used. For example, instead of a full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses.

I tried to put a simple select statement like `'select * from mydatabase.dbo.table1'` instead of `'mydatabase.dbo.table1'`

```
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read()
     .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
      .option("dbtable", "select * from mydatabase.dbo.table1")
      .option("user", "username")
      .option("password", "password")
      .load();
```

but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'select'
```

I tried to put extra parenthese to englobe the select statement but this time I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'WHERE'.
```

Can anyone know if how can we get the result of a query in spark with java?

thanks a lot

Comment: Or [Spark SQL - load data with JDBC using SQL statement, not table name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34365692/9613318)

Comment: Specifically it has to be `(SELECT ...) AS alias` or `(SELECT ...) alias`, not `SELECT ...` or `(SELECT ...)`

Comment: thank youy a lot user9613318 , it works!!